# how to retrieve pgp secret key of gnupg v2 using bouncycastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg

I'm looking to extract the secret keys in the .gnupg folder with the newer version of gnupg. In the previous versions, there was a secring.gpg file that could be read.

It is in this example: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/PGPExampleUtil.java

Now this is gone and all keys are stored in the pubring.gpg file. How can the secret key be read through Bouncy Castle?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring)?